# ServiceStack.Text Deserialize json to object always converts to string and behaves strangely with quotes

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

What I'm trying to do:

I have json objects that have values which could be string, ints, doubles, or lists of any of these. I'm trying to deserialize these json strings into C# objects, but because they could have multiple types, I'm stuck using the generic object, rather than a strongly typed alternative.

My issue: It appears as though the ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(jsonString) function behaves oddly in cases where T = object. It will always treat things as a string, and does not work with quotes.

Here's an example:

```
string json1 = "[1]";
string json2 = "[1,2]";
string json3 = "['hello']";
string json4 = "['hello','world']";
string json5 = "[\"hello\"]";
string json6 = "[\"hello\",\"world\"]";
object o1 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json1);
object o2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json2);
object o3 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json3);
object o4 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json4);
object o5 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json5);
object o6 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<object>(json6);
```

Expected Underlying object:

```
object    type           value
o1        List           [1]
o2        List           [1,2]
o3        List           ['hello']
o4        List           ['hello','world']
o5        List           ["hello"]
o6        List           ["hello","world"]
```

Actual Underlying object:

```
object    type           value
o1        String         "[1]"
o2        String         "[1,2]"
o3        String         "['hello']"
o4        String         "['hello','world']"
o5        String         "["
o6        String         "["
```

For reference, the corresponding code block using Newtonsoft.Json interprets the underlying objects as Netwonsoft.Json.Link.JArray.

As it currently stands, I would have to ensure single quotes are used in the json, and then deserialize any string that was extracted recursively until everything has been properly extracted.

Is there something I can do to have this behave the way I'd like using ServiceStack.Text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack's text serializers work by converting the JSON into the specified schema, when you use object it's not possible to infer the type ahead of time, so in order to do this at runtime ServiceStack's JSON Serializer needs to emit a proprietary **__type** metadata property that tells the deserializer what to deserialize it into. This only gets emitted for **JSON Object literals** and not arrays which is why it doesn't work here.

Here are some ways to deserialize an array:

```
string json6 = "[\"hello\",\"world\"]";

var list = json6.FromJson<List<string>>();
list.PrintDump();

var array = json6.FromJson<string[]>();
array.PrintDump();

var arrayObj = json6.FromJson<object[]>();
arrayObj.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response -- that makes sense. While slightly less elegant looking, it does appear as though I can simply treat everything as an object array, and single strings or values are appropriately deserialized as a length one array with the proper object literal. My friendly suggestion would be to add implicit handling on "[/* ... */]" to act as an array, but that's just my 2 cents :)

Have any insight on why double quotes would break the string case?

Comment: Sure add the failing test [as a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues) so everyone can keep track of it.

Comment: I know that it is an old answer, but I'm wondering if we still couldn't choose to emit the __type property for arrays knowing the risks ? Or could I write extension methods that will be called during serialization and deserialization of arrays ?